# In general what's the difference in dev. vs staging part of website?

Tags: php, live, staging

What's code wise the difference between dev and staging fase of a website?

I mean dev <-> live, than live all code is clean/minimized, right?

Any info, real life "code" part examples?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### dev

- No compressed/minified/etc. code
- Likely to be separate for each developer
- Not updated from VCS but the code that resides there is committed at some point
- May contain not-working code (usually yet uncommitted)

#### staging

- Updated from VCS
- Should have the exactly same setup (lib versions etc) as production
- Testing setup for code that is supposed to go in production
- Some code is likely to be minified to see if it breaks anything.

#### production

- Well.. production ;)